Formatting table with plots
Can someone help me format this table: I would like a little bit of space between the plots and the upper and lower margin of their respective cells. I dont know how to make the weaky relu function to be in one line.
Important: the width of the table cannot be increased since I am working on a two column document
\documentclass[9pt, landscape, twocolumn]{extarticle}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}[English]

\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=black, breaklinks=true]{hyperref}

\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{pifont}

\usepackage[most,listings]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{colframe=white}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\usepackage{multirow}

% Margins
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
a4paper,
left=0.75in,
right=0.75in,
top=1in,
bottom=1in
}

% Header and footer
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\justifying

% Titles
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\section}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\normalsize\bfseries}


\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.25}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{itemsep=0pt, topsep=0pt}

% Plots
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5} % Increase the height of the row
        \begin{tabular}{|p{2.5cm}|p{2.5cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2.5cm}|p{2.5cm}|}
            \hline
            \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Sigmoid}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Tanh}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{ReLU}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Leaky ReLU}}\\ \hline
            \centering $g(z) = \frac{1}{1+e^{-z}}$ & \centering $g(z) = \frac{e^{z} - e^{-z}}{e^{z} + e^{-z}}$ & \centering $g(z) = \max(0, z)$ & 
                \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}p{2.5cm}@{}}
                $g(z) = \max(\epsilon x, x)$ \\
                $\epsilon \ll 1$
                \end{tabular}\\ \hline
            \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(current bounding box.center)}, yshift=0.5cm]
                \begin{axis}[
                    axis x line=middle,
                    axis y line=middle,
                    ytick={0, 0.5, 1},
                    xtick={0},
                    width=4cm,
                    height=4cm,
                    % grid style={dashed, gray!30},
                    xmin=-6,     % start the diagram at this x-coordinate
                    xmax= 6,    % end   the diagram at this x-coordinate
                    ymin= -0.5,     % start the diagram at this y-coordinate
                    ymax= 1.5,   % end   the diagram at this y-coordinate
                    %axis background/.style={fill=white},
                    xlabel=x,
                    ylabel=y,
                    tick align=outside,
                    enlargelimits=false]
                  % plot the stirling-formulae
                  \addplot[domain=-6:6, Blue, ultra thick, samples=500] {1/(1+exp(-x))};
                \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture} & 
            \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(current bounding box.center)}, yshift=0.5cm]
                \begin{axis}[
                    axis x line=middle,
                    axis y line=middle,
                    ytick={-1, 0, 1},
                    xtick={0},
                    width=4cm,
                    height=4cm,
                    % grid style={dashed, gray!30},
                    xmin= -2,     % start the diagram at this x-coordinate
                    xmax= 2,    % end   the diagram at this x-coordinate
                    ymin= -1.5,     % start the diagram at this y-coordinate
                    ymax= 1.5,   % end   the diagram at this y-coordinate
                    %axis background/.style={fill=white},
                    xlabel=x,
                    ylabel=y,
                    tick align=outside,
                    enlargelimits=false]
                  % plot the stirling-formulae
                  \addplot[domain=-4:4, Blue, ultra thick, samples=500] {(exp(x) - exp(-x))/(exp(x) + exp(-x))};
                \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture} &  
            \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(current bounding box.center)}, yshift=0.5cm]
                \begin{axis}[
                    axis x line=middle,
                    axis y line=middle,
                    ytick={-1, 0, 1},
                    xtick={1},
                    width=4cm,
                    height=4cm,
                    % grid style={dashed, gray!30},
                    xmin= -2,     % start the diagram at this x-coordinate
                    xmax= 2,    % end   the diagram at this x-coordinate
                    ymin= -1.5,     % start the diagram at this y-coordinate
                    ymax= 1.5,   % end   the diagram at this y-coordinate
                    %axis background/.style={fill=white},
                    xlabel=x,
                    ylabel=y,
                    tick align=outside,
                    enlargelimits=false]
                  % plot the stirling-formulae
                  \addplot[domain=-4:4, Blue, ultra thick, samples=500] {max(0, x)};
                \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture} & 
            \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(current bounding box.center)}, yshift=0.5cm]
                \begin{axis}[
                    axis x line=middle,
                    axis y line=middle,
                    ytick={-1, 0, 1},
                    xtick={1},
                    width=4cm,
                    height=4cm,
                    % grid style={dashed, gray!30},
                    xmin= -2,     % start the diagram at this x-coordinate
                    xmax= 2,    % end   the diagram at this x-coordinate
                    ymin= -1.5,     % start the diagram at this y-coordinate
                    ymax= 1.5,   % end   the diagram at this y-coordinate
                    %axis background/.style={fill=white},
                    xlabel=x,
                    ylabel=y,
                    tick align=outside,
                    enlargelimits=false]
                  % plot the stirling-formulae
                  \addplot[domain=-4:4, Blue, ultra thick, samples=500] {max(0.1 * x, x)};
                \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}

\end{document}



Welcome to teX.SE! Please make your given code snippet be compilable, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

@Mensch Thanks, what do you mean with compatible?

He meant compilable, not compatible. Compilable means that your question contains code which we can copy&paste and run on our machines, so that your question is self-contained. Without any of that best we can do is guesswork.

You could enlarge the bounding box of your tikzpictures.

@Skillmon Ah okey, thanks. I edited the que question such that it can be copied and pasted

@Skillmon I tried enlarging the bounding box but somehow is not working

@juan19.99 Don't you get errors from your preamble about symbols already defined?

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz
I am actually getting:
Command \ulcorner' already defined. Command \urcorner' already defined.
Command \llcorner' already defined. Command \lrcorner' already defined.
Command \Asterisk already defined.
But it lets me compile it

@juan19.99 If there is an error, it does not let you compile the document. After an error, latex only recovers enough to syntax check the rest of the document, not necessarily producing sensible output. You should never ignore error messages.

You could use the tabularray package, which makes it very easy to add additional space to specific rows:
\documentclass[9pt, landscape, twocolumn]{extarticle}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  a4paper,
  left=0.75in,
  right=0.75in,
  top=1in,
  bottom=1in
}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{
  colspec={cccc},
  vlines,hlines,
  cells={valign=m},
  row{1}={font=\bfseries},
  row{2}={mode=dmath},
  cell{2}{4}={mode=text},
  row{3}={rowsep=10pt}% <= adjust additional space here
}

    Sigmoid & Tanh & ReLU & Leaky ReLU\\ 
    g(z) = \frac{1}{1+e^{-z}} & g(z) = \frac{e^{z} - e^{-z}}{e^{z} + e^{-z}} & g(z) = \max(0, z) & 
        {$g(z) = \max(\epsilon x, x)$ \\
        $\epsilon \ll 1$}
        \\ 
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(current bounding box.center)}, yshift=0.5cm]
        \begin{axis}[
            axis x line=middle,
            axis y line=middle,
            ytick={0, 0.5, 1},
            xtick={0},
            width=4cm,
            height=4cm,
            % grid style={dashed, gray!30},
            xmin=-6,     % start the diagram at this x-coordinate
            xmax= 6,    % end   the diagram at this x-coordinate
            ymin= -0.5,     % start the diagram at this y-coordinate
            ymax= 1.5,   % end   the diagram at this y-coordinate
            %axis background/.style={fill=white},
            xlabel=x,
            ylabel=y,
            tick align=outside,
            enlargelimits=false]
          % plot the stirling-formulae
          \addplot[domain=-6:6, Blue, ultra thick, samples=500] {1/(1+exp(-x))};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture} & 
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(current bounding box.center)}, yshift=0.5cm]
        \begin{axis}[
            axis x line=middle,
            axis y line=middle,
            ytick={-1, 0, 1},
            xtick={0},
            width=4cm,
            height=4cm,
            % grid style={dashed, gray!30},
            xmin= -2,     % start the diagram at this x-coordinate
            xmax= 2,    % end   the diagram at this x-coordinate
            ymin= -1.5,     % start the diagram at this y-coordinate
            ymax= 1.5,   % end   the diagram at this y-coordinate
            %axis background/.style={fill=white},
            xlabel=x,
            ylabel=y,
            tick align=outside,
            enlargelimits=false]
          % plot the stirling-formulae
          \addplot[domain=-4:4, Blue, ultra thick, samples=500] {(exp(x) - exp(-x))/(exp(x) + exp(-x))};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture} &  
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(current bounding box.center)}, yshift=0.5cm]
        \begin{axis}[
            axis x line=middle,
            axis y line=middle,
            ytick={-1, 0, 1},
            xtick={1},
            width=4cm,
            height=4cm,
            % grid style={dashed, gray!30},
            xmin= -2,     % start the diagram at this x-coordinate
            xmax= 2,    % end   the diagram at this x-coordinate
            ymin= -1.5,     % start the diagram at this y-coordinate
            ymax= 1.5,   % end   the diagram at this y-coordinate
            %axis background/.style={fill=white},
            xlabel=x,
            ylabel=y,
            tick align=outside,
            enlargelimits=false]
          % plot the stirling-formulae
          \addplot[domain=-4:4, Blue, ultra thick, samples=500] {max(0, x)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture} & 
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(current bounding box.center)}, yshift=0.5cm]
        \begin{axis}[
            axis x line=middle,
            axis y line=middle,
            ytick={-1, 0, 1},
            xtick={1},
            width=4cm,
            height=4cm,
            % grid style={dashed, gray!30},
            xmin= -2,     % start the diagram at this x-coordinate
            xmax= 2,    % end   the diagram at this x-coordinate
            ymin= -1.5,     % start the diagram at this y-coordinate
            ymax= 1.5,   % end   the diagram at this y-coordinate
            %axis background/.style={fill=white},
            xlabel=x,
            ylabel=y,
            tick align=outside,
            enlargelimits=false]
          % plot the stirling-formulae
          \addplot[domain=-4:4, Blue, ultra thick, samples=500] {max(0.1 * x, x)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}\\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}


